# Why does using rev as your man pager fail when piping it through rev again?

Tags: bash, man, pager

I recently thought about a devious trick that involves setting the `PAGER` envionment variable to `rev` as a joke.
When I tried reading the man page for rev with `man rev` I then saw the man page in reverse as expected.

If you want to try this without setting your pager you can use the `-P` option in `man` like so: `man -P rev rev` and you will see the man page for `rev` in reverse.

The thing that confuses me is that you cannot simply pipe the output through rev to get it the right way around again. I tried running `man -P rev rev | rev` and instead of getting the output the right way around, it is still reversed.

There is an error message displayed the correct way around, it looks like this:

```
mdoc warning: A .Bl directive has no matching .El (#58)
```

I presume this is in the correct direction because it came through `stderr` and not `stdout`

If you simply pipe it through rev again, all of the text is in the correct direction, error message and all.

```
man -P rev rev | rev | rev
```

What is the reason for this odd behaviour?

I am using bash in gnome terminal on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `man` does not use the pager unless output is sent to a terminal. If output is sent to a pipe instead, it will merely `cat` the output there. And so...

```
man rev | rev | rev
```

...and...

```
man -Prev rev | rev | rev
```

...are equivalent.